# Group array in batches

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I'm a bit stuck trying to develop a solution to an array I need to group by a property, I think it has to be very easy but...

I have a list of Suppliers that must be treated in a batch process grouped by status.

```
public class SupplierDetails
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

The list of Suppliers will have different status and SupplierId, the Suppliers needs to be processed in the order they are inserted into the list so, I need to send to a process an array of the first Suppliers that have the same Status, once processed I have to send to that process the next Suppliers that have the same status, and so on...

A sample of what the list looks like

```
[SupplierId=1,Status='C'],[SupplierId=2,Status='C'],[SupplierId=3,Status='A'],[SupplierId=4,Status='C']
```

The result list would let me send the Suppliers to the BatchProcess in this way

```
BatchProcess([SupplierId=1,Status='C'],[SupplierId=2,Status='C'])
BatchProcess([SupplierId=3,Status='A'])
BatchProcess([SupplierId=4,Status='C'])
```

Another explanation would be... "So when you have AAABBBABABA you would want the first three in a group, then the next three in a group and then a bunch of individual items" thanks to @Chris

Right now, the solution I develop is not very pretty but uses generics

```
  public List<IEnumerable<T>> FlattenBatchedArray<T, Y>(IEnumerable<T> arr, Func<T, Y> getPropertyValue)
    {
        if (arr == null || arr.Count() == 0 || getPropertyValue == null)
            return null;

        var listArr = arr.ToArray();
        int indexSkip = 0;
        int indexTake = 0;
        var groupedList = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();

        while (indexTake < listArr.Length)
        {
            indexSkip = indexTake;
            var currentValue = getPropertyValue(listArr.ElementAt(indexSkip));
            indexTake = Array.FindIndex(listArr, indexSkip, x => !getPropertyValue(x).Equals(currentValue));
            if (indexTake == -1)
                indexTake = listArr.Length;
            var next = listArr.Skip(indexSkip).Take(indexTake - indexSkip);
            groupedList.Add(next.ToList());
        }
        return groupedList;
    }
```

This functions passes all the tests I need

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod3()
{
    var listPO = new List<SupplierDetails>();
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 1, Status = "O" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 2, Status = "C" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 3, Status = "C" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 4, Status = "O" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 5, Status = "O" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 6, Status = "O" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 7, Status = "C" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 8, Status = "O" });

    var result = FlattenBatchedArray(listPO, (x) => x.Status);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 5);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].Count(), 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].Count(), 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[2].Count(), 3);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[3].Count(), 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[4].Count(), 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(0).Status, "O");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(0).Status, "C");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(1).SupplierId, 3);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(1).Status, "C");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[2].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 4);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[2].ElementAt(0).Status, "O");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[2].ElementAt(1).SupplierId, 5);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[2].ElementAt(1).Status, "O");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[2].ElementAt(2).SupplierId, 6);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[2].ElementAt(2).Status, "O");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[3].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 7);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[3].ElementAt(0).Status, "C");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[4].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 8);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[4].ElementAt(0).Status, "O");

    listPO = new List<SupplierDetails>();
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 1, Status = "O" });
    result = FlattenBatchedArray(listPO, (x) => x.Status);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 1);

    listPO = new List<SupplierDetails>();
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 1, Status = "O" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 2, Status = "O" });
    result = FlattenBatchedArray(listPO, (x) => x.Status);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].Count(), 2);

    listPO = new List<SupplierDetails>();
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 1, Status = "O" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 2, Status = "C" });
    result = FlattenBatchedArray(listPO, (x) => x.Status);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].Count(), 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].Count(), 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(0).Status, "O");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(0).Status, "C");

    listPO = new List<SupplierDetails>();
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 1, Status = "O" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 2, Status = "O" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 3, Status = "C" });
    result = FlattenBatchedArray(listPO, (x) => x.Status);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].Count(), 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].Count(), 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(0).Status, "O");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(1).SupplierId, 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(1).Status, "O");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 3);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(0).Status, "C");

    listPO = new List<SupplierDetails>();
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 1, Status = "O" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 2, Status = "C" });
    listPO.Add(new UnitTestProject2.SupplierDetails() { SupplierId = 3, Status = "C" });
    result = FlattenBatchedArray(listPO, (x) => x.Status);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].Count(), 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].Count(), 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[0].ElementAt(0).Status, "O");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(0).SupplierId, 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(0).Status, "C");
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(1).SupplierId, 3);
    Assert.AreEqual(result[1].ElementAt(1).Status, "C");
}
```

Comment: If you have a working solution, what is the question?

Comment: I guess that there has to be a solution using groupBy or something like that that would be more elegant than going through an iterator.

Comment: Since you create multiple groups for the same value of an attribute, using `GroupBy` would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more generic solution you can write some extension method like:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> SequentialGroupBy<TSource, TSelector>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSelector> selector)
{
    if (!source.Any())
        return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<TSource>>();

    var result = new List<List<TSource>>();
    result.Add(new List<TSource> { source.ElementAt(0) });

    foreach (var item in source.Skip(1))
    {
        if (selector(result.Last()[0]).Equals(selector(item)))
            result.Last().Add(item);
        else
            result.Add(new List<TSource> { item });
    }
    return result;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var result = collection.SequentialGroupBy(item => item.Status).ToList();
```

Notice that this still consumes the entire collection

---

A pure linq version of the extension method that will benefit from linq's deffered execution will be:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> SequentialGroupBy<TSource, TSelector>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSelector> selector)
{
    if (!source.Any())
        return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<TSource>>();

    var prevSelector = selector(source.First());
    int groupingIndex = 0;

    return source.Select(item =>
    {
        var currentSelector = selector(item);
        if (!prevSelector.Equals(currentSelector))
        {
            prevSelector = selector(item);
            groupingIndex++;
        }
        return new { groupingIndex, currentSelector, item };
    }).GroupBy(item => new { item.groupingIndex, item.currentSelector }, select => select.item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution which doesn't enumerate the input sequence more than once:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Batch<TKey, TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var buffer = new List<TSource>();

    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        if ((buffer.Count > 0) && !Equals(keySelector(element), keySelector(buffer.Last())))
        {
            yield return buffer.ToArray();
            buffer.Clear();
        }

        buffer.Add(element);
    }

    if (buffer.Count > 0)
        yield return buffer.ToArray();
}
```

(This also handles the case where one of the keys is null, although that's probably not a requirement.)

[EDIT: I simplified it after realising that I didn't need a `prev` variable because I could just use `buffer.Last()`.]

Comment: Nice the use of yield!